# Javascript - How to return a string from a regex instead of [Object object]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent form component and a child component which I'm using for auto-completing text input.
I'm passing an array of objects called autoCompTxt that has a name and id field, from the Parent component to the Child component.

```
//Parent:
const [obj, setObj] = useState([{name:'',id:''}]);
<AutoCompleteText onChange={text => setName(text)} autoCompTxt={obj} name="sampleName" id="sampleId" />
```

In the child component I'm trying to filter on the name string, using 'v.name'. But the suggestions array gets populated with Objects instead of Strings.

```
//Child:
let suggestions = [];
suggestions = props.autoCompTxt.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v.name));
console.log(suggestions);
```

AutoCompleteText.js:22 Suggestions: [object Object],[object Object]

I've tried using JSON.stringify() and `${v.name}`. But they haven't helped.

The issue is that the line below is returning 2 objects. {name:"name1", id:1},{name:"name2", id:2}

instead of returning just the names. "name1","name2"

suggestions = props.autoCompTxt.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v.name));

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Input } from 'reactstrap';
const AutoCompleteText = props => {

    const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const onTextChanged = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;

        let suggestions = [];

        if (value.length > 0) {
            setSuggestions([]);
            const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, 'i');
            console.table(props);
            suggestions = props.autoCompTxt.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v.name));
            console.log('Suggestions: ' + suggestions);

        }
        setSuggestions(suggestions);
        setText(value);
    }

    function suggestionSelected(value) {
        setSuggestions([]);
        props.onChange(value);
        setText(value);
    }

    function renderSuggestions() {
        if (suggestions.length === 0) {
            console.log(suggestions);
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <ul>
                {suggestions.map((item) => <li onClick={() => suggestionSelected(item)}>{item}</li>)}
            </ul>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Input value={text} onChange={onTextChanged} type="text" />
            {renderSuggestions()}

        </div>
    )
};

export default AutoCompleteText;
```

Comment: Explain the question in detail , what you are doing is correct , add details of AutoCompleteText and Suggestion component to understand better

Comment: I've added the full script to the question.

Comment: I have added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array of strings (v.name) after filtering, map a new array:

```
suggestions = props.autoCompTxt
              .sort()
              .filter(v => regex.test(v.name))
              .map(v => v.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in render suggestion you cannot pass an object directly to dom , you need to pass only one value

```
            <ul>
                {suggestions.map((item) => <li onClick={() =>suggestionSelected(item)} key={item.id}>
                {item.name}
                 </li>)}
            </ul>
```